# Java for loop passing variable

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the following code :

```
double getTotalPayments(){
    for (int i = 0 ; i == periodsPerYear * years ; i++){
      double balance =+ Math.round(initialBalance - (monthlyPayment-((interestRate/periodsPerYear) *initialBalance))*100.00)/100.00;
      initialBalance =- balance;
      if(i == periodsPerYear*years){
        return balance;
        break;
      }
    }
    return balance;
  }
```

I'm trying to pass the double variable 'balance' for the method to return. I have to use the for loop to calculate the total amount of payments. Any suggestions on how to fix it? I've tired everything I can think of.

Comment: Your end condition in your for loop should be 'i < periodPerYear * years'

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing a few things within the code. It would probably go something like this. You were just missing the bits within the method declaring that it's either a public or private method, and that you weren't calling in the Int Variable balance.

```
public double getTotalPayments(int balance){
for (int i = 0 ; i == periodsPerYear * years ; i++){
  double balance =+ Math.round(initialBalance - (monthlyPayment-((interestRate/periodsPerYear) *initialBalance))*100.00)/100.00;
  initialBalance =- balance;
  if(i == periodsPerYear*years){
    return balance;
    break;
  }
}
return balance;
```

Please let me know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
double balance += Math.round(initialBalance - 
(monthlyPayment-((interestRate/periodsPerYear) 
 *initialBalance))*100.00)/100.00;

initialBalance -= balance;
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you return balance when "balance" is only a local variable in for loop? And another like @NomadMaker said that the condition for the for loop should be "i < periodPerYear * years".